# Error sending mail with Civimail

Tags: wordpress, civimail

I've switched hosts and the new host's smtp server seems to be rejecting the email I'm trying to send to a group.  It can me 2 or 2000 people with the same response.  Apparently it does not like the auto generated sender email address?  Anyone have that issue and go I d a solution?  CiviCRM on WordPress. Both very recent versions.

2017-09-22 16:30:04 [4342] H=(www.sportingdetectiondogs.ca) [184.154.247.100]:33676 I=[184.154.247.116]:25 X=TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:128 CV=no SNI="sportingdetectiondogs.ca" F= A=dovecot_login:civicrm@sportingdetectiondogs.ca rejected RCPT : SITEGROUND: b.304.14831.47c90fe51b65dc14@sportingdetectiondogs.ca is not a valid address: Sender verify failed: Sender verify failed
2017-09-22 16:40:04 [48178] H=(www.sportingdetectiondogs.ca) [184.154.247.100]:42556 I=[184.154.247.116]:25 Warning: SITEGROUND: Message from 184.154.247.100. Normal SMTP auth with civicrm@sportingdetectiondogs.ca system user: sporti62
2017-09-22 16:40:04 [48178] H=(www.sportingdetectiondogs.ca) [184.154.247.100]:42556 I=[184.154.247.116]:25 X=TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:128 CV=no SNI="sportingdetectiondogs.ca" F= A=dovecot_login:civicrm@sportingdetectiondogs.ca rejected RCPT : SITEGROUND: b.304.14832.46cd2e439db32d78@sportingdetectiondogs.ca is not a valid address: Sender verify failed: Sender verify failed
2017-09-22 18:45:24 [26529] H=(www.sportingdetectiondogs.ca) [77.104.151.189]:51718 I=[77.104.151.189]:465 Warning: SITEGROUND: Message from 77.104.151.189. Normal SMTP auth with civicrm@sportingdetectiondogs.ca system user: sporti62
2017-09-22 18:45:24 [26529] 1dvXdM-0006tt-Ja <= info@sportingdetectiondogs.ca H=(www.sportingdetectiondogs.ca) [77.104.151.189]:51718 I=[77.104.151.189]:465 P=esmtpsa X=TLSv1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:128 CV=no SNI="usm31.siteground.biz" A=dovecot_login:civicrm@sportingdetectiondogs.ca S=565 M8S=0 T="Test for SMTP settings" from  for support@siteground.com
support@support.com [~]#

Comment: I'm interested in this because I also had a (different) problem with sending mail via my hosting provider (SiteGround) see https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20657/syntax-error-from-civimail. From the error message or log quoted that you might also be hosting with them. Would be nice to know as we might have issues in common!

Comment: I posted in your thread.

Answer (score 1):

two possible sources of the error:

- you have changed something in the configuration of your mail accounts in civi (or didn't finish the config previously), check the documentation, the "localpart" should not be empty but name of your bounce mailbox (eg if your mailbox is bounce@example.org, it should be "bounce+")
- civimail relies on a trick that most servers implement: if you send and email to bla+whatever@example.org, it will automatically be understood as an alias of bla@example.org

It seems that you need to at least fix the localpart, as your new mail server is more strict and better at catching configuration problems